# Can't post comment even if it's 15 character long

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, comments

I tried posting a comment **@Greg Cain: Great!!!!!** which is about 22 character long, while trying posting it says

> Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.

See the picture:

[image]

Please indicate me if i am doing any thing wrong.

**Edit:** It's not accepting "@Greg Cain: Greater!!!!!" even, which include 15 alphabets.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not considering the @-reference as part of the comment. Not to mention that after clicking submit, the @-reference to Greg's username is going to be stripped out. Since you're commenting on his answer, explicitly referencing the OP is unnecessary as they will be notified of a new comment on their answer.

While the gesture of thanking the user in words is appreciated, voting has a more tangible effect. Give the up-vote a click and/or accept his answer, and call it done.

Comment: Thanks for the kind response, and I always do what you suggested in second paragraph, but i think this would be really guiding for new users. Thanks again.

Comment: @rptwsthi Was the voting help text useful in alerting you to the fact that we like people to vote for things they feel is great? Perhaps it's more of a problem with explaining votes than it is tying to prevent trivial comments in terms of length.

Comment: @bmike Sorry, i don't wanna sound dumb, but this was complicated english to understand.

Comment: Good answer.  Marked [tag:status-bydesign]